# Refreshing custom ribbon button which relies on a table to get the label and image

Tags: vba, ms-access, ribbonx

I have a custom ribbon and one of the buttons on it (image and label for the button) are supposed to change based on what happens in one of the forms (so, essentially, it's supposed to change when values in a table change and making changes in the form is the trigger for the change).

On the CLOSE button of the form I have the following code:

```
sbRefreshRibbon
MyRibbon.Invalidate
```

and here is what the procedure does, so the MyRibbon.Invalidate part is probably redundant:

```
Public Sub sbRefreshRibbon()
On Error GoTo RestartApp
MyRibbon.Invalidate
On Error GoTo 0
Exit Sub
RestartApp:
  MsgBox "Please restart Application for Ribbon changes to take effect", _
    vbCritical, "Ribbon Refresh Failed"
End Sub
```

In any case, sometimes, when clicking CLOSE I get the "Please restart Application for Ribbon changes to take effect" error. After restarting, all is well, the label is correct and so is the image
but, how can I make the label and image change without errors and restarts?

Comment: The first action is to catch the original error message and this can give you some clue. I propose to either temporarily comment the On Error line or display the original error message with your custom message ( use this code instead of yours "MsgBox "Please restart Application for Ribbon changes to take effect" & Chr$(13) & Err.Number & ":" & Err.Description,  vbCritical, "Ribbon Refresh Failed"" )

Comment: hey again :) there's only one line in there, MyRibbon.Invalidate lol. and nothing else can be erroring from what i understand. however, after i posted, i removed that line from the OnClose code (since it seems to be redundant. i got this piece from someone's db but now that i think about it, i'm not sure why they did it this way, theyre literally repeating the same line thats in the previous procedure) and it seems to work. i will play with it some more and post back

Comment: The form may block any `Invalidate` calls while it is open. Try to prevent doing that from the form's code.

Comment: @EugeneAstafiev any idea how i can do it if not from the form? since the form triggers the change. and thank you for all your help on these

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to call the `Invalidate` method of the `IRibbonUI` interface multiple times. You need to left a single call as soon as your form is closed.

Also you may consider using the [InvalidateControl](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/office.iribbonui.invalidatecontrol) method of the `IRibbonUI` interface instead. It allows invalidating the cached value for a single control (not the whole custom UI) on the Ribbon user interface.

Comment: hey, can you please explain the 2nd part? lost me there lol. and yeah, i figured it's redundant, i copied it from someone's db. but i since removed it and i'm still getting that message, i can't catch when and why. my impression is that it happens after i make design changes even if theyre not related to the ribbon. just any design changes on the form trigger that message